# MS Access DB connection error in Rest Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am trying to connect ms access db (mdb/accdb file) available in network/shared drive inside REST API/Webmethods using C# code. The same code is working fine if I use console application but throwing connection error if used in Rest API i.e. the call is made using Rest API( VS 2013) .

Exception :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=External component has thrown an exception.
  Source=System.Data
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
```

Code :

```
 string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12;" + @"Data Source=\\network folder\Shared\filesecure.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=somepassword;Persist Security Info=true;";

using (OleDbConnection oledbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{

connection.Open(); // Getting exception here
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try testing your web methods using a database file located on the same machine. If that works then the problem is likely due to the account running the web service code not having permission to access LAN resources (e.g., a shared folder on another machine).

Comment: also, be aware that the web service may be running as x64 bits - this would mean you need to use the x64 bit driver for ACE, not the defaulted x32 one.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with the help of above responses

Service is running on x64 bits, required to install AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe drivers for that. I had 32 bit office on my machine.

Additional steps

a.  First delete mso.dll entry from registry at HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\FilesPaths

b. Install AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive /quiet using command prompt from your set up location